# Build failed on Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm very new to Xamarin framework and I'm learning it by following tutorials on Xamarin site. When I compile the code using Visual Studio 2015, I got "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll" error. I've been searching through web for solution and couldn't find any to resolve the issue. So, here I'm hoping to get an answer.

[Tutorial on Xamarin Site](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/)

EDIT : Screenshot of reference screen

[image]

EDIT : Screenshot after adding System and System.Net

[image]

Edit : Screenshot with new errors

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a repeatable example of the code you are having a problem with?

Comment: The link will take you to the tutorial that I'm having an issue.

Comment: The tutorial is one thing, but you are having an issue with your code. It would be much better to look as a small repeatable example using *your* code, not the tutorials. It could be you are just missing a reference or something, but you should have a reference to `System` by default, unless you copied the whole thing by hand into an empty solution.

Comment: Could you provide a list of the references you have in your project?

Comment: These are the references I have for Winphone project : Analyzers | .Net for Windows Store apps | Microsoft.Phone | Phoneword | Windows Phone 8.1 | Xamarin.Forms.Core | Xamarin.Forms.Platform | Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT | Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Phone | Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

Comment: I don't see a `System` in there. Instead of typing out a list here in comments, could you take a screen capture of your references in the project, and add that to your question?

Comment: Ok so I updated my post with screengrab. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a reference to `System` .Net library.

Comment: So I added System.Net library but doesnt resolve the issue. But it's kind of strange that System does not show up in reference list even though message said it is added. You can see it in the screenshot.

Comment: Not `System.Net` just `System`. It is a .Net library.

Comment: But that gives me whole new set of errors. I tried Net Framework 4, 4.5 and 4.6.1. You can see them in the new screenshot

Comment: Looks like you are missing `System.ServiceModel.Activation` reference now. You need to keep following your errors and resolve your reference issues as it says in the error.

Comment: You seem to have several issues with your source code. We resolved problem you were having in your initial question, but I also added a more general answer that should cover the other related issues stemming from missing references. Could you accept that, and if you have other issues then post another question and we will be glad to help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you do not have all the needed assembly references. Simply follow the errors and add the references that it says it cannot resolve.

Comment: I kept adding all those assemblies but the strange thing was, it went into full circle and I ended up with the very first error - "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll". Since winphone project is not that important to us, I just removed it and the error is gone. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: It could be that there is a conflicting library somewhere that provides `System.SystemException` instead of `System`. You could try going back through and adding all the missing library references, then remove `System` reference and see if that fixes your problem. Alternatively, to try to track it down properly, examine each of the libraries and see if it provides a `System.SystemException` class.